# How do I make a grid with heat data?

Tags: c++, game-design, simulations, visualization

So I am working on a game in which I am working on a temperature system that goes  about like this;

Lines of latitude will be markers across the map, starting at 1 (north pole) going to 200 (south pole) Each latitude line will have its own number box,(poles will have very low numbers, and equator will have very high numbers) and on the first day, a number will be picked from this box for every line. Then the next day, a new number will be generated, but it cannot be more than 5 degrees from the previous value.

the thing is, I don't know how to do any of this, i am forced to use c++ because that is what Unreal Engine uses. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you should start with some beginner Unreal tutorials to get a foundation in the basics of the engine, and consider learning its Blueprint scripting system, which should be quite adequate for this task.

Comment: When you don't know enough yet to even identify and articulate any specific problems you have with this undertaking and are just standing in front of a large "I don't know how to do any of this" wall, then you might not yet be ready for a project like that.